# Scons: how to create a file path by appending two nodes?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to write an sconstruct file that will install headers in a destination directory.  The intended effect is:

```
cp include/a.h ../dest/a.h
cp include/b.h ../dest/b.h
```

Or just as good:

```
cp include/a.h ../dest/include/a.h
cp include/a.h ../dest/include/b.h
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
env = Environment()
for header in Glob("include/*.h"):
    env.Command(Dir("../dest").Append(header), header, Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
    env.Alias("includes", Dir("../dest").Append(header));
```

This obviously doesn't work because there's no Append function.  Glob returns Node objects, and a Dir is also a Node object.  I can't figure out how I'm supposed to combine two Node objects into a longer path.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to paste those paths together on your own (thanks for describing the actual problem that you're trying to solve). You're looking for the already provided `Install()` method. Please also check the [User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), chap 11 "Installing Files in Other Directories: the Install Builder", but a concrete solution should look something like this (from the top of my head):

```
env = Environment()
includes = env.Install("../dest", Glob("include/*.h"))
env.Alias("includes", includes)
```

And if you should ever **really** need this

```
str(node)
```

will return the path of the `node` in question. `;)`